# Openssl decryption using a public key

Tags: linux, openssl

I need to decrypt a file which is encrypted using a private key. I have a public key which I can use to decrypt this file. How can I do this. I did:

```
openssl rsautl -in file -inkey key.pem
```

But this is not working. This shows the error as:

```
unable to load Private Key
3074128072:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public keys cannot be used to decrypt, they can only be used to encrypt and to verify the encryption signature.

Comment: but for me this is all what I have... can i convert that public key to a private key aand then decrypt it... is it possible?

Comment: Not without the other factor.

Comment: i m not getting what u r trying to say.

Comment: the encryption should be done with *your* public key, and the decryption with the matching private key (which, obviously, only you have) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: that is all what i am getting on searching also... but the problem with me is what i said... there would be some solution to that.. but i will have to either to a lot a research on that...

Comment: public key can't be converted to a private key to decrypt what is encrypted by the original private key. This is just impossible, and it's the foundation of the ssl/tls security model. If a public key can be somehow twisted to decrypt the cipher, then there's no security here.

Comment: This answer is not technically true. The underlying mechanism of RSA encrypt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption) can be used with either public or private key. The same can be said about the underlying mechanism of RSA decryption.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to everyone, you can in fact decrypt using a Public Key, *only however*, if your data was encrypted with the appropriate Private Key.

As to how you go about decrypting it, from what I can see the openssl utility doesn't ship with this functionality. It seems you would have to use something that utilises the OpenSSL C API (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/RSA_public_decrypt.html).

Either use the C API directly or something like PHP's bindings to OpenSSL.

Comment: This is typically handled with signing APIs. Signing is done with the private key so anyone with the public key can verify the authenticity.

Comment: I found a way to do this via OpenSSL's `rsautl` subcommand. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Openssl CLI can achieve "decrypting with the public key" via the `rsautl` subcommand like so:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -in data.sig -raw -hexdump
```

**Note:** here, "decrypt" is loosly defined as [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation), and the API used is actually the `-verify` algorithm. Warning that rolling your own crypto is not advised, and misusing RSA is easy to do to create a broken security system.