# openssl/RSA - Using a Public key to decrypt

Tags: linux, openssl, rsa

I'm looking to secure the software update procedure for a little device I'm maintaining that runs Linux. I want to generate an md5sum of the update package's contents and then encrypt that hash with a private key before sending it out to the customer. When they load the update, the device should then decrypt the hash, verify it, and proceed with installation of the package.

I'm trying to do this with OpenSSL and RSA. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045956/openssl-decryption-using-a-public-key) thread, and was discouraged. I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908825/rsa-decryption-using-the-public-key-in-perl) thread and wondered how Perl gets around the purported impossibility of it all. I'm doing this in C, so perhaps there's a parallel function in an SSL library somewhere?

So my question really is: can I force command line Linux to take a public key as the decryption input, or perhaps use C to circumvent that limitation?

Thanks in advance, all.

Comment: Sidenote: you *encrypt* with public keys and decrypt with *private* keys. You can also sign with a private key (which, for RSA, is identical to decryption) and verify with a public key (which, for RSA, is identical to encryption).

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped to clarify the answer. Also, when I ran the commands in the answer (signing and verifying) the output of the signing looked encrypted and the output of the verification was plain text. I don't understand how what you said works, then, unfortunately. How can decryption (signing) look like garbled text while encryption (verifying) looks clean?

Comment: RSA encryption and decryption are inverses of each other. They can be run in any order. So, for a message, `M`, `Encrypt(Decrypt(M)) == M` and `Decrypt(Encrypt(M)) == M`.

Comment: Oh, of course. So I take it the vocabulary choice in RSA is really more to indicative which keys are used for what than it is to indicate what the output will look like. Thanks again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's assume you have generated a public and private RSA key using `openssl genrsa`:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out mykey
Generating RSA private key, 512 bit long modulus
...++++++++++++
..........++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
$ openssl rsa -in mykey -pubout -out mykey.pub
writing RSA key
```

You can sign something with the private key like this:

```
$ md5sum myfile | openssl rsautl -inkey mykey -sign > checksum.signed
```

You can verify this data using the public key:

```
$ openssl rsautl -inkey mykey.pub -pubin -in checksum.signed
df713741d8e92b15977ccd6e019730a5  myfile
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Though, as my comment on the above post indicates, I'm not sure how this works/why the vocabulary is different, etc. It does do what I want it to, though, so thank you.

Comment: You are now signing the textual output of md5sum instead of directly signing/verifying "myfile". **WARNING** Using MD5 or a 512 bit RSA key is of course completely insecure here.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I recommend you use the sign and verify routines instead of trying to implement them yourself with the underlying RSA encrypt and decrypt routines.

Nonetheless, Openssl CLI can achieve "decrypting with the public key" via the `rsautl` subcommand like so:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -in data.sig -raw -hexdump
```