# Recover RSA signature data using .net

Tags: c#, .net, openssl, rsa

Is there a .net equivalent way to reproduce the following openssl command:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey public_key.pem -in signature.dat -out recovered_data.dat
```

This verifies the signature and outputs the recovered data.  I know it may be unconventional to recover the data, but it contains some useful information (not just a hash/digest from a message) from some other system.

According to the .net docs for [RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifydata?view=net-6.0) or [RSA.VerifyData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.verifydata?view=net-6.0), RSA functions can not recover the data, only verify the signature.  But perhaps there is a way to use decrypt methods, like what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584255/519657) is mentioning.

(note: I do not need to save the recovered data to a file, just need it returned from an RSA method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Decrypt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.decrypt?view=net-8.0) method is specifically intended for *regular* decryption, which requires a *private* key. An alternative that allows the desired decryption of the signature with the public key is C#/BouncyCastle.

The C# Code below gives the *same* result as the posted *openssl rsautl -verify* statement if the same input data is used for public key and signature:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using System;
using System.IO;

...

string publicX509Pem = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAunF5aDa6HCfLMMI/MZLT
5hDk304CU+ypFMFiBjowQdUMQKYHZ+fklB7GpLxCatxYJ/hZ7rjfHH3Klq20/Y1E
bYDRopyTSfkrTzPzwsX4Ur/l25CtdQldhHCTMgwf/Ev/buBNobfzdZE+Dhdv5lQw
KtjI43lDKvAi5kEet2TFwfJcJrBiRJeEcLfVgWTXGRQn7gngWKykUu5rS83eAU1x
H9FLojQfyia89/EykiOO7/3UWwd+MATZ9HLjSx2/Lf3g2jr81eifEmYDlri/OZp4
OhZu+0Bo1LXloCTe+vmIQ2YCX7EatUOuyQMt2Vwx4uV+d/A3DP6PtMGBKpF8St4i
GwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
byte[] signature = Convert.FromHexString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

// Import public X.509/SPKI key, PEM encoded
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(publicX509Pem));
AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKeyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();

// public decrypt
IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
cipher.Init(false, publicKeyParameter);
byte[] decrypted = cipher.ProcessBlock(signature, 0, signature.Length);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(decrypted)); // 3031300D060960864801650304020105000420D7A8FBB307D7809469CA9ABCB0082E4F8D5651E46D3CDB762D02D0BF37C9E592
```

In the example *0x7E1D...2249* is the PKCS#1 v1.5 (or more precisely [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-8.2)) compliant signature of the SHA256 hashed message *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*.
The decrypted plaintext *0x3031...E592* is the DER encoding of the [`DigestInfo`](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEINeo-7MH14CUacqavLAILk-NVlHkbTzbdi0C0L83yeWS) value, consisting of the digest OID for SHA-256 and the message hash.